# PHP form validation (don't know how to split it in two different pages)

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms

I am working on a contact form in PHP. My knowledge of PHP is pretty much non-existent.

I've tried for a while to get a HTML form to submit to PHP form to have its text fields validated and required if blank but couldn't get anything to work. I also don't know AJAX, otherwise, would have attempted that.

So, have resorted to having a PHP self-form inside the HTML page.

This is the current version:

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$firstNameErr = $lastNameErr = $emailErr = $messageErr = "";
$first_name = $last_name = $email = $message = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["first-name"])) {
     $firstNameErr = "First name is required";
   } else {
     $first_name = test_input($_POST["first-name"]);
   }

    if (empty($_POST["last-name"])) {
     $lastNameErr = "Last name is required";
   } else {
     $last_name = test_input($_POST["last-name"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
     $messageErr = "Message is required";
   } else {
     $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
   }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>
```

This is the form on the same page:

```
<form class="ui form"  method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
  <div class="field">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input name="first-name" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
     <span class="error">* <?php echo $firstNameErr;?></span>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input name="last-name" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
     <span class="error">* <?php echo $lastNameErr;?></span>
  </div>
    <div class="field">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" type="email">
     <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea rows="2" placeholder="Please type in your message" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
     <span class="error">* <?php echo $messageErr;?></span>
  </div>

  <button class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Is there a way to do this in two different pages, ie, form in first page, and carried over to the second page in sessions mode? Or is this acceptable for a commercial site? Please let me know. Thank you.

**Addendum**

```
   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
      $email = filter_vars(test_input($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
   }
```

**Addendum 2**

I have included this at the bottom of the php stuff, ie, after the function test_input.`header('location: php_mailer_form.php');` Is that the correct placement of it?

But for some reason when I attempt to visit the contact.php form it doesn't even show up, it just goes straight to the error form which I have at the bottom of the php_mailer_form.php.

```
 if(!$mail->send()) {
        header('location: url/contactError.html');

    } else {
        header('location: url/contactResult.html');

    }
```

Why? (please let me know if I need to include additional information).

**Addendum 3**

```
<?php

session_start();

$first_name = $_SESSION['first-name'];
$last_name = $_SESSION['last-name'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$message = nl2br($_SESSION['message']);

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'host_specified';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'email_specified';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password_specified';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587; 

$mail->addReplyTo( $email, $first_name );
$mail->addAddress( $email, $first_name );
$mail->addAddress( 'email_specified', 'Staff' );
$mail->From = 'email_specified';
$mail->FromName = 'Staff';


$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Hotel Room Request';
$mail->Body    = $message; 

$mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    header('location: url/contactError.html');

} else {
    header('location: url/contactResult.html');

}
```

**Addendum 4**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Contact</title>



  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">
    .ui.fixed.sticky + p {
        margin-top: 39px;
      }

      .error {
        color: #FF0000;
      }

  </style>
</head>


<body>

<?php
session_start(); //allows use of session variables

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (!isset($_POST["first-name"])) {
     $firstNameErr = "First name is required";
   } else {
     $first_name = test_input($_POST["first-name"]);
   }

    if (!isset($_POST["last-name"])) {
     $lastNameErr = "Last name is required";
   } else {
     $last_name = test_input($_POST["last-name"]);
   }

   if (!isset($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
   }

   if (!isset($_POST["message"])) {
     $messageErr = "Message is required";
   } else {
     $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
   }

   if(isset($first_name) && isset($last_name) && isset($email) && isset($message))
   {
     $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
     $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
     $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
     $_SESSION['message'] = $message;

     header("Location: contact9Sessions.php");
   }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>

<div class="ui container">
<div class="ui segment">
  <div>

    <div class="ui fluid five item tabular menu">
      <a class="item" href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a class="item" href="about.html">About</a>
      <a class="item" href="rooms.html">Rooms Info & Rates</a>
      <a class="item" href="book.html">To Book</a>
      <a class="item" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </div>

  </div>

<div class="ui two column stackable grid">

<div class="ten wide column">

<form class="ui form"  method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
  <div class="field">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input name="first-name" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
     <?php if(isset($firstNameErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $firstNameErr . '</span>'); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input name="last-name" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
     <?php if(isset($lastNameErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $lastNameErr . '</span>'); ?>
  </div>
    <div class="field">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" type="email">
     <?php if(isset($emailErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $emailErr . '</span>'); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea rows="2" placeholder="Please type in your message" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
     <?php if(isset($messageErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $messageErr . '</span>'); ?>
  </div>

  <button class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
  </div>

  <div class="six wide column">
    <br><br>
    <img class="ui centered large bordered rounded image" src="images/tobereplaced.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="ui two column grid">
  <div class="ui left aligned ">
    <p>Left Footer Stuff Here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="ui right aligned">
    <p>Right Footer Stuff Here</p>
  </div>

</div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your intention, but usually its better to submit the form to the same page so you can report the errors that often occur(as you are doing). What you can do though, is once you have verified the credentials, set a session variable "$_SESSION['userisloggedin']" and then use "header" to send the user to the page you desire(e.g. pageyoucanonlyseeifloggedin.php) and at the top of this page have php code "if(!(isset($_SESSION['userisloggedin']))) header("location:"login.php"")" to send them back to login screen if they are not allowed see the page

Comment: @AndrewB, hi, thanks for your comment. um. regarding sessions, it has nothing to do with logging users in/out at all. it had to do with carrying over to another php page, hence why i wanted to be able to collect the variables in a sessions mode as my understanding is that's the only way to be able to carry them over to multiple pages.

Comment: @AndrewB, also based on what I've posted above, would you think this is acceptable  for commercial usage? Please let me know.

Comment: You could use it, but you could stand to use more validation. Also, your form will send `$_POST` attributes to your other page.

Comment: Hmm, still not sure I fully understand your intentions. If you want to save the email, knowing that it is correct, setting the variable $_SESSION['email'] = $email; $_SESSION['first-name']=$first_name; should allow you to save all the variables for a session. remember to call "session_start();" before trying to use or assign a session variable

Comment: @Rasclatt, how so? I'm really not that great in PHP, and have been driving myself crazy trying to figure out bits and pieces. If you can profer additional information to make the form commercial-worthy, I would seriously appreciate it.

Comment: Hmm, I have made a small sample project for friends that had the intention to teach php, I believe it covers this. if you want to give me your email, i can send it over to you

Comment: @AndrewB, as of now, my intention is (assuming that the form above is commercial-worthy and being able to carry it in session-mode) is to carry it over to php-mailer form so it can be emailed to the user and staff of the site.

Comment: Whether it is commercially worthy or not completely depends on what you are doing with that data. if you are taking those values and storing them in a database, then no. That isn't nearly good enough.

Comment: @AndrewB, no plans to store them in a DB at all. only plans to get it to a php-mailer form (and by php-mailer form, I meant this: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). and to have it emailed to client and staff.

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765 Presuming you are sending an email, it should suffice with one extra validation in there for `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);` You just have to safeguard agains a spammer using your form to send junk mail (using multiple headers like Cc and Bcc).

Comment: @Rasclatt, and once I figure out how to use `filter_vars($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);`, it'll make it commerical-worthy? Sorry if I seem a little too oriented to that It's just this is my first php form (like literally), and it is going into commercial useage (a first for me as well). So, I want to make sure that I cover all the bases as much as possible so I can release the project with a peace of mind, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Yes, if you are just sending the data in an email, that should suffice, however if the staff of the site intend to use that data to store anything in the database, they should be advised not to assume that data is completely safe, they should take their own precautions in adding it to a database. Do you understand the concept of the session_start(); and session variables? will I add a formal answer?

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765 When making an email form, the two common exploits are sending spam and 2nd is formatting an email with HTML to make the user think it's something it is not, so `filter_vars($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` takes care of spamming, `htmlspecialchars()` converts html to special characters so they can't embed html.

Comment: @AndrewB, please do add a formal answer if you can. I do have a couple of practice form with session_start() which worked, but they're very different from this. If the formal answer can show me how to do it with a self-form, I would appreciate it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Rasclatt, please look at the addendum, if you have the time. Is that the correct usage of  `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start(); //allows use of session variables

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (!isset($_POST["first-name"])) {
     $firstNameErr = "First name is required";
   } else {
     $first_name = test_input($_POST["first-name"]);
   }

    if (!isset($_POST["last-name"])) {
     $lastNameErr = "Last name is required";
   } else {
     $last_name = test_input($_POST["last-name"]);
   }

   if (!isset($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
   }

   if (!isset($_POST["message"])) {
     $messageErr = "Message is required";
   } else {
     $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
   }

   if(isset($first_name) && isset($last_name) && isset($email) && isset($message))
   {
     $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
     $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
     $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
     $_SESSION['message'] = $message;

     header("Location: php_mailer_form.php");
   }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>



<form class="ui form"  method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
  <div class="field">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input name="first-name" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
     <?php if(isset($firstNameErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $firstNameErr . '</span>'); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input name="last-name" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
     <?php if(isset($lastNameErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $lastNameErr . '</span>'); ?>
  </div>
    <div class="field">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" type="email">
     <?php if(isset($emailErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $emailErr . '</span>'); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea rows="2" placeholder="Please type in your message" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
     <?php if(isset($messageErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $messageErr . '</span>'); ?>
  </div>

  <button class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now in your other page, to access the variables, simply call "session_start();" at the top of the page as we did here, then use call "$_SESSION['message']" to get the value of message. Does this answer your question? Also note, I edited the html so that the error message div only prints if the error variable was set.

Comment: oh wow. Thank you! Let me attempt it, and will get back to you on this. I appreciate this!

Comment: I have a question which I posted underneath `Addendum 2` in my question above. Would appreciate your input. Thank you.

Comment: Header is designed to change page. you are changing the page before the html gets sent to the user. I don't know how this mailer works, but I imagine you want to "include" the mailer file rather than change to that page. i.e. include("php_mailer_form.php"); doing this effectively takes the code from that file and slaps it straight into the file that calls it. once its there, you can use whatever functions/classes it defines

Comment: If you use header, any following PHP code will not run, since you are getting to this piece of code and saying "okay, we need to go to another page and run its code, forget about this one"

Comment: ok. Then, how do I have it sent to another php form? Ok. See, I have a php_mailer_form.php that is in session mode, so it should collect it from this form. But how do I get that accomplished? I thought that putting the header thing at this self-php form would accomplish that. Please pardon me if I'm being a tad slow.

Comment: Hmm, its very hard to make the correct calls without seeing the structure. could you maybe add the code for phpmailerform? maybe we can identify the problem

Comment: please give me a minute. Thanks.

Comment: I've put the php_mailer_form.php underneath Addendum 3.

Comment: Everything looks in order from this perspective. You set all your variables, then change to mailer, within the mailer you use the variables to send the mail. I'm assuming the mailer is working correctly. Do these pages "url/contactResult.html" and "url/contactError.html" exist? Only other thing I can think of, I'm not sure if the word "location" is case sensitive, I use "Location" and that works, perhaps try capitalising it.

Comment: Okay so before, with the header under the function, we were always changing to the mailer form, before the html could be written. I edited it so that we would check if all the values are correct, if they are set the session variables and only then change to the mailer form. please let me know if this solves it

Comment: um ... let me give the good news first. The contact form shows up! And if I fill it out completely, it gets emailed! The bad news is that when I test the submit form if empty, it doesn't even show the error messages, ie, `First name is required`, etc. It just goes straight to the error page on the php_mailer_form.php.

Comment: I have to go now. But will definitely look back later either today, or tomorrow (sorry, so much other stuff). So appreciate you taking the time to work with me on this. If you still have time to work on this, I really appreciate it. Please do let me know if you have further questions on my stuff.

Comment: Will do, its about time for me to go as well. I'll have a think about it.

Comment: Ah I think its a simple matter, perhaps declaring the error variables at the start counts as "setting" them. Delete the lines where we declare them all = "". Perhaps that will do it. Let me know.

Comment: Also, I changed your use of "empty()" to "isset()" as I believe it is a little more encompassing in this case. see https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/ please test the code in my answer again

Comment: hey, sorry for the delay! I have attempted your latest version, and the problem persists, ie, if I hit submit button while all fields are blank, it goes straight to the `contactError.html` page at the bottom of the `php_mailer_form.php`. If I fill out all the fields, it works, ie, it gets emailed. If I try to fill out only a couple, it again goes straight to the `contactError.html` page. It doesn't even trigger the warnings. Appreciate if you have time to look at it again. Tried to save you time in varying your answer, but none of them worked.So befuddled.

Comment: also, to make troubleshooting easier, I've posted the php form in its entirety in addendum4. Hope it helps. As for php_mailer_form.php, it's still intact as it is.

Comment: you know what? I think I'll make it a new question. You did answer my original premise, ie, how to have it carried over via sessions even though it was still on the same page. And you've been so helpful. I just realized it's unfair that I'm still asking you for help since the problem is now different. So, for that, I'll accept your answer and will post a link to the new question.

Comment: here's the link to the new question if you have any inclination to troubleshoot on that. Really appreciate the time you took to answer this question. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32897698/error-with-php-form-non-functional

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic form send example. This can all be on one page. PHP at the top, before all the html loads to browser, `<form>` html down anywhere in the `<body>` of the html page:

**EDIT:**
I have updated the code to include your PHP Emailer.

```
<?php
class EmailEngine
    {
        public  static  function Send($settings = false)
            {
                $email          =   (!empty($settings['email']))? $settings['email']:false;
                $first_name     =   (!empty($settings['first-name']))? $settings['first-name']:false;
                $last_name      =   (!empty($settings['last-name']))? $settings['last-name']:false;
                $message        =   (!empty($settings['message']))? $settings['message']:false;
                $alt_message    =   (!empty($settings['alt_message']))? $settings['alt_message']:'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';

                require(__DIR__.'/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
                $mail = new PHPMailer;
                $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
                $mail->Host = 'host_specified';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
                $mail->Username = 'email_specified';                 // SMTP username
                $mail->Password = 'password_specified';                           // SMTP password
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
                $mail->Port = 587; 
                $mail->addReplyTo( $email, $first_name );
                $mail->addAddress( $email, $first_name );
                $mail->addAddress( 'email_specified', 'Staff' );
                $mail->From = 'email_specified';
                $mail->FromName = 'Staff';
                $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
                $mail->Subject = 'Hotel Room Request';
                $mail->Body    = $message; 
                $mail->AltBody = $alt_message;

                return $mail->send();
            }
    }

// Just make an error reporting function to return errors
function error_report($val = false)
    {
        $array["first-name"]    =   "First name is required";
        $array["last-name"]     =   "Last name is required";
        $array["email"]         =   "Email is required";
        $array["message"]       =   "A message is required";

        return (isset($array[$val]))? $array[$val] :false;
    }
// Sanitize. I add false so no error is thrown if not set
function sanitize_vals($data = false)
    {
        if(empty($data))
            return false;

        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }


// If a value is posted (any will do from your form) process the rest of the $_POST
if(isset($_POST["first-name"])) {
        // Just loop through the $_POST instead of doing all the manual if/else...
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
                // This specifically processes your email address
                if(($key == 'email')) {
                        // If not valid email, send to errors
                        if(!filter_var($value,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                            $errors[$key]   =   error_report('email');
                        else
                            $payload[$key]  =   $value;
                    }
                // This processes the rest
                else {
                        $value  =   sanitize_vals($value);  
                        // Checks for empty
                        if(empty($value))
                            $errors[$key]       =   error_report($key);
                        else
                            $payload[$key]  =   $value;
                    }
            }
        // If all is good and no errors set, send the email
        if(!isset($errors)) {
                // SEND MAIL HERE.
                $page   =   (EmailEngine::Send($payload))? "Result" : "Error";
                header("Location: url/contact{$page}.html");
                exit;
            }
    }
?>

<form class="ui form"  method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <div class="field">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input name="first-name" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['first-name'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['first-name'],ENT_QUOTES);?>" />
        <span class="error">* <?php if(!empty($errors['first-name'])) echo $errors['first-name'];?></span> </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input name="last-name" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['last-name'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['last-name'],ENT_QUOTES);?>" />
        <span class="error">* <?php if(!empty($errors['last-name'])) echo $errors['last-name'];?></span> </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['email'])) echo preg_replace('/[^0-9a-zA-Z\@\.\_\-]/',"",$_POST['email']);?>" />
        <span class="error">* <?php if(!empty($errors['email'])) echo $errors['email'];?></span> </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea rows="2" placeholder="Please type in your message" name="message" id="message"><?php if(!empty($_POST['message'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message'],ENT_QUOTES);?></textarea>
        <span class="error">* <?php if(!empty($errors['message'])) echo $errors['message'];?></span> </div>
    <button class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```