# Error with PHP Form - Non-functional

Tags: php, html, forms

Trying to get this form to work. Have posted the code in its entirety.

It doesn't work, ie, if all fields are blank, it goes straight to the `contactError.html` page in the `php_mailer_form.php` page. (have posted the `php_mailer_form.php` at the bottom.

It works if *all the fields* are filled out.

If empty, or partially filled out, it doesn't trigger any error messages. Just goes straight to the `contactError.html`.

What am I missing here? I've tried so many different variations of making this work, and none of them to date have.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title> Contact</title>

  <style type="text/css">
      .error {
        color: #FF0000;
      }

  </style>
</head>


<body>

<?php
session_start(); //allows use of session variables

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (!isset($_POST["first-name"])) {
     $firstNameErr = "First name is required";
   } else {
     $first_name = test_input($_POST["first-name"]);
   }

    if (!isset($_POST["last-name"])) {
     $lastNameErr = "Last name is required";
   } else {
     $last_name = test_input($_POST["last-name"]);
   }

   if (!isset($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
   }

   if (!isset($_POST["message"])) {
     $messageErr = "Message is required";
   } else {
     $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
   }

   if(isset($first_name) && isset($last_name) && isset($email) && isset($message))
   {
     $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
     $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
     $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
     $_SESSION['message'] = $message;

     header("Location: php_mailer_form.php");
   }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>

<div class="ui container">
<div class="ui segment">
  <div>

    <div class="ui fluid five item tabular menu">
      <a class="item" href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a class="item" href="about.html">About</a>
      <a class="item" href="rooms.html">Rooms Info & Rates</a>
      <a class="item" href="book.html">To Book</a>
      <a class="item" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </div>

  </div>

<div class="ui two column stackable grid">

<div class="ten wide column">
<form class="ui form"  method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
  <div class="field">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input name="first-name" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
     <?php if(isset($firstNameErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $firstNameErr . '</span>'); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input name="last-name" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
     <?php if(isset($lastNameErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $lastNameErr . '</span>'); ?>
  </div>
    <div class="field">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" type="email">
     <?php if(isset($emailErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $emailErr . '</span>'); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea rows="2" placeholder="Please type in your message" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
     <?php if(isset($messageErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $messageErr . '</span>'); ?>
  </div>

  <button class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
  </div>

  <div class="six wide column">
    <br><br>
    <img class="ui centered large bordered rounded image" src="images/tobereplaced.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="ui two column grid">
  <div class="ui left aligned ">
    <p>Left Footer Stuff Here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="ui right aligned">
    <p>Right Footer Stuff Here</p>
  </div>

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the `php_mailer_form.php`

```
<?php

session_start();

$first_name = $_SESSION['first-name'];
$last_name = $_SESSION['last-name'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$message = nl2br($_SESSION['message']);

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'host_specified';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'email_specified';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password_specified';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587; 

$mail->addReplyTo( $email, $first_name );
$mail->addAddress( $email, $first_name );
$mail->addAddress( 'email_specified', 'Staff' );
$mail->From = 'email_specified';
$mail->FromName = 'Staff';


$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Hotel Room Request';
$mail->Body    = $message; 

$mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    header('location: url/contactError.html');

} else {
    header('location: url/contactResult.html');

}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try my answer the last time you asked this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853422/php-form-validation-dont-know-how-to-split-it-in-two-different-pages

Comment: You can't call `session_start()` after you output HTML. It has to be done before any output. If you had warnings enabled, you would see the warning "Headers already sent".

Comment: *...smells like a duplicate to me* ^

Comment: @Fred-ii- Me thinks you might just be right.... *as usual!*

Comment: @Rasclatt or... maybe not. See below... V V V V V

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think that's a carry-over from previous. I think the OP may have been led to believe sending a form email was more difficult than it was. This problem was mentioned in previous question *(in the comments)* but not addressed in the answer....so I guess it could be considered *new*.

Comment: @Rasclatt no word from the OP, so it's anybody's game now. I'll skip this round.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Close that tab.... *sniff* *sniff*

Comment: @Rasclatt ciao for now, *a presto!*

Comment: @Rasclatt, hey, sorry for delayed response. the only reason why i didn't try your answer is simply because i am responsible for this form. remember when i asked if it's commercial-worthy? your answer, i'm sure, would work. the problem is that, i didn't know how to read your answer, nor make modifications should it be required in the future. i wanted to stick with something that i could be comfortable tinkering with should the need arise. i hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Rasclatt, also, and, if it was bad form to create a new question, mea culpa. i was trying to avoid what is sometimes complained about, ie, asking more than one question in a question.

Comment: Yeah, it's alright not a problemo! My comment is really that you don't need to use all the sessions. The answer that you accepted is no more commercial than mine, and if you try it (copy yours first, don't overwrite it) you shouldn't have a problem with those error messages. I don't want to dissuade you from the other answer though, I just thought you may have some luck with the answer I gave. If not, no big deal! I can probably help you with what you have already.

Comment: Looks like you got your answer working! Good luck! Cheers!

Comment: @Rasclatt, sorry for the misunderstanding, i didn't mean that the other answer is more commercial-worthy. what i meant, is that at least it's something i could personally modify. anyway, thank you for your patience and kindness. really appreciate you not taking it personally that i didn't accept your answer. Happy Friday! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `isset()` to test if a form field is filled in. If a form field is empty, it will be set to the empty string when the form is submitted, and `if (!isset($_POST['fieldname']))` will not detect it. Use `empty()` instead:

```
if (empty($_POST['first-name'])) {
    $firstNameErr = "First name is required";
} else {
    $first_name = test_input($_POST["first-name"]);
}
```

Comment: hey thanks! sorry for delayed response. this answer worked with one slight exception. not sure if it's good form to create another question, or not. anyway, when hitting submit button if all fields are empty, the warnings are triggered. so that's good news. however, when i try to fill one field, and then hit submit button, the warnings erupt for all the empty fields, but for the one that's filled out, it blanks out whatever I've written in there. how do i fix this? or should i create it as another question? thank you for your time.

Comment: Put `value="<?php if(isset($first_name)) { echo $first_name; }?>"` in the `<input>` tag to copy the previous value.

Comment: You can also add the `required` attribute to all the inputs, and the browser won't let them submit the form at all.

Comment: that worked! Thank you! =) Happy Friday! (at least in my part of the world, it's a Friday!)

Comment: To confirm, what Barmar said about isset being wrong here, that is true, my mistake earlier! So you should change those 4 tests to be "empty". Move the block of PHP code in the first file to before the <html> tag, and add your doctype.

Comment: What earlier mistake are you referring to?

Comment: In the other question those others were referring to, I told user to use isset instead of empty, which he was using initially